# Relative path in Context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, context.xml

Is there a way to set a relative path to the **docBase** attribute in the context.xml of a web application, so it is outside of the appBase directory of the tomcat server instance?

I would like to be able to share the context configuration between computers and have the app living in a directory, not a war file. That way i can compile the classes directly into that directory (in my project development directory) and have tomcat use these classes without any copying/packaging needed.

I am using the tomcat 8.0.0-RC5.
My directory Layout is:

```
/home/david/projects/frontend/web-content          <-- the static html files
/home/david/projects/frontend/web-content/WEB-INF  <-- the WEB-INF with the web.xml
/home/david/projects/tomcat                        <-- tomcat base directory
/home/david/projects/tomcat/Catalina/localhost     <-- holds the frontend.xml context configuration
```

I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/frontend" docBase="../../frontend/web-content">
</Context>
```

but that did not work. The whole path before /web-content seems to be ignored. The log says:

```
The main resource set specified [/home/david/projects/tomcat/webapps/web-content] is not valid
```

The [Tomcat 8 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) for the context container says:

> You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory of the owning Host.

Does relative here mean a strict subdirectory of appBase (no .. allowed)?

Setting an absolute path works without problems. The configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/frontend" docBase="/home/david/projects/frontend/web-content">
</Context>
```

works, but it is specific to my computer. So I cannot share the context configuration without modification anymore.

I could create a symbolic link inside the appBase directory of the tomcat server and let it point to the web-content folder of my application. This would work, but I would have different configurations (symbolic links) on linux and windows machines.

Comment: How exactly is `appBase` set in server.xml?

Comment: I did not change the Host configuration in the server.xml so it is still the default value: <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just taking only the last name of relative path names and ignoring the first parts
is most likly a bug in tomcat. Relative path names should work or must throw errors.
But ignoring parts is bad.
A workaround could be using an absolute path name like this:
`<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/../www.war"`

I just reading the changelog of Tomcat 8.0.15.
The bug should be fixed(!):
 "Correctly handle relative values for the docBase attribute of a Context."